# CSS: cant align elements horizontal in li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok this is the effect Im trying to achieve:

[image]

And the according HTML:

```
<div class = "options">
          <a href = "#" class = 'bot-link' value = 2><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Close</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h3 value = 0>say hi</h3>
                  <p>(press L)</p>
                  <img src = "../resources/plus.png"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h3 value = 1>Like</h3>
                  <p>(press L)</p>
                  <img src = "../resources/plus.png"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h3 value =2>commiserate</h3>
                  <p>(press L)</p>
                  <img src = "../resources/plus.png"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h3 value =3>Ask</h3>
                  <p>(press L)</p>
                  <img src = "../resources/plus.png"/>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
```

I need to horizontally align (with the image in the center vertically of the h3 space) and the p all on the same line within the

. My problem is I cant achieve this and have a weird same line issue with first 2 lis:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
.options ul {
    margin-left: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.options ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        float: left;
}
.options {
    float: left;
position: fixed;
margin-left: 50%;
left: 50%;
/* background: black; */
margin-left: -100px;
padding: auto;
z-index: 10;
width: 200px;
top: 33%;
}

.options ul li h3 {
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
        transition: all 90ms ease-out;

}

.options ul li p {
    display: none;
}

.options img {
    width: 30px;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You might be looking for line-height

Answer (score 0):

The `h3` and `p` tags are [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) (i.e. `display: block` by default), so they will each take up a whole 'line' and push the images onto the next line.

Apply `display: inline-block` to the `h3` elements (and `p` elements) and you should get what you're after. Example on the `h3`:

```
.options ul li h3 {
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all 90ms ease-out;

    /* add this */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The left float on `.options ul li` also might be causing a separate issue, but I'm not sure if it's an effect you want.